# Mapping routes for urls with .asp extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to create a legacy route to redirect old asp links to the new urls.

My route is as follows and it's the first route in the list:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", // Route name
    "{*path}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Legacey", action = "Legacey" },
    new { path = @".*\.asp.*" });// Parameter defaults
```

The problem I have is IIS intercepts these and 404s them before they hit my route.
I guess there's a setting in the web.config to tell IIS to stop doing this but I can't find it.

Comment: Do the asp files physically exist? If not, they're being picked up by the StaticFileHandler, which will return a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this through URL rewriting, as explained in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx)

Just add something like this to your web.Config (replace Legacey/Legacey with the redirect URL for the asp pages):

```
<system.webServer> 
  <rewrite> 
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Redirect ASP Files to new URL" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="*\.asp" /> 
        <action type="Redirect" url="Legacey/Legacey" appendQueryString="false" /> 
      </rule> 
    </rules> 
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I haven't tested this, it's just what I've understood from that post.

Comment: What will this do if the asp file actually exists?  Is there a way to have it use the file if it's present, but redirect if it's NOT present?